# Is my work haram given that I write software which has an "insurance" field?

Tags: halal-haram, work, insurance, software

I work as a programmer for a shipping company. My job requires me to create a program which contains fields like "shipper's name", "address", etc. Also there are fields which provides information about the item being shipped, such as weight, size, etc.

There is also another field which I must provide and it is called the "insurance amount" field. This field will contain the amount the shipper paid if he paid for insurance.

Note that I do not know what is being shipped and who is shipping it. I just make the program where these fields get automatically populated when some one from the shipping office sends the information. The program then takes the information and stores it somewhere else. I never deal with the information directly nor do I have any information about how or what kind of insurance they have. I am just required to provide the fields.

Is my work considered haram for this?